# Logfile per Component Hierarchy

Tags: log4net

I have the following problem:

```
ComponentA with Unique Name
   ChildComponent
      ChildChild
   AnotherChild
```

Everytime a new instance of ComponentA is created I want to redirect the output to a unique file named ComponentA-UniqueName including all child component log entries.

How can this be achieved?

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution which works pretty fine for us:

http://gist.github.com/387423

Daniel

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box, dynamically changing appenders is hard to do. I would consider logging to a different medium, like a database table, that enables filtering and grouping log data.

**Update:**

Using [contexts](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/contexts.html) you can provide per-instance information across instance boundaries. Consider the following implementations:

```
class ComponentA
{
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        using(log4net.ThreadContext.Stacks["component"].Push(this.Id))
        {
            childComponent.DoStuff();
        }
    }
}

class ChildComponent
{
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        using(log4net.ThreadContext.Stacks["component"].Push(this.Id))
        {
            childChild.DoStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever messages are logged (regardless of which component does the logging), the current context stacks are included. In your appender configuration, use the `%property{component}` formatter to output the content of the component stack which will include ids of both the `ComponentA` instance and the `ChildComponent` instance.

Comment: @Daniel: nice. Though I'm still not sure why you cannot do this using the logger hierarchy that is already built-in. Of course, output to unique files is a challenge. But again, I would rather consider a database for this job since it would be trivial to select and group on whatever data you choose to log.

Comment: Hy peter,
When using a database the problem remains the same. I need to uniquely identify the log source according to a component. So I need to give the loggers in my component hierarchy meaningful names according to their instance data to distinguish them in the database. Logger per class wouldn't work.

Comment: I see. Think I misunderstood your problem initially. See my updated answer, I believe you could use the context stuff, though I understand you have something working now..

Comment: Hy Peter,The problem here is that the component hierarchy has different threads accessing different components. But all information logged in the hierarchy must be added to the same log file.